# for loop can't find value in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i'm trying to solve the dna problem in the cs50 course and to solve it i made a small scale version wherein i made a value and the program would search the csv file for that value but for some reason it can't find it.

here's the code:

```
import csv

f = open("small.csv")
csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))
length=len(csv_f)

target=4
for a in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        if csv_f[a][j]==target:
            print("found")
```

i even tried using for j in range(length-1): and making target into a string through target="4" but it still didn't work can someone help me pls

Comment: Can you post an example of the data in `small.csv`?

Comment: Why are you using `range(length)` as the length of a row?

Comment: Why compare a string to an integer? The read in data comes in as strings inside a list of lists ,,, comparing against an inter is always False.

Comment: since you state that you've also tried `"4"`, I expect that @Barmar has posed the right question for you.  The use of a single dimension for two is incorrect.  This makes sense only if the CSV file you're referencing is "square".  It would probably help to see the CSV, but even without it, since the logic seems sound, I think you're likely getting "lost" because the CSV is not "square."

Answer (score 1):

This is because the values from the CSV file are strings. And the object you are trying to evaluate to ie `target` is an integer value of `4`.

So change the `target = 4` to `target = "4"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size.

You don't need to explicitly iterate over the range of the length, python's iterator syntax just allows you to do a for-each for rows in your row list, and then values in each row.

```py
csv_rows = list(csv.reader(f))

for row in csv_rows:
   for value in row:
      if value == TARGET_VALUE:
         print("found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file has the same number of fields as rows (which would be an incredible coincidence), you shouldn't use `length` as the limit of the inner loop. It should use the length of a row as the limit, not the number of rows, i.e. `for j in range(len(csv_f[a])):`.

But it's unpythonic to loop over lists using `range()`. Just use `for variable in list:`

```
for row in csv_f:
    for cell in row:
        if cell == target:
            print("found"):
```

You can also simplify this further by using the built-in `any()` function and `in` operator:

```
if any(target in row for row in csv_f):
    print("found")
```

Another problem is that `csv.reader()` returns all the fields as strings. So your target needs to be a string, not a number.

```
target = '4'
```